# Action mailer SMTP google apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, gitlab

I tried to configure actionmailer to send via google apps with smtp.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "mydomain.com",
:user_name            => "username",
:password             => "password",
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

However whenever gitlab tries to send an e-mail:

```
Sent mail to user@my.domain.com (10ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 29ms

535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted
```

Server runs ruby 1.9.3p194. Why doesn't google apps accept the username/password?

Comment: Try logging into your gmail account , you may need to grant permissions for your app

Comment: @KyleC I already tried that. My app is the action mailer. Would I need to grant permissions for SMTP?

Comment: No.... Are these errors occuring in development (local computer) or production?

Comment: It's production. I changed the username to username@my.domain.com and now it seems like it's working. I'm not familiar with that app (GitLab) so I'm not sure if I"m restarting it correctly to apply the config changes (I use the init script /etc/init.d/gitlab) but it's .. quirky. Anyway I really appreciate your help. Let's consider the issue resolved for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works now, I think the problem was with the username. it needs the domain in the username. i.e.  the problem was

```
user_name: 'username'
```

Whereas the correct way (at least for google apps) is

```
user_name : 'username@mydomain.com'
```

Answer (score 5):

this works for me:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "gmail.com",
:user_name            => "you@gmail.com",
:password             => "password",
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Try setting the domain to gmail.com

Comment: Thank you, that works for me too for gmail.com but not for google apps domain. Thank you though.