# Configuring gitlab the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, smtp, gitlab

Note : I have read many posts of gitlab after that process I have no option but to post as new question. Please dont assume it as a duplicate.

Hello everyone,

My apologies if my questions sound silly . I have posted after quite a trial and error on gitlab . 
FYI : I am alien to ruby.

I and my colleagues are trying to configure gitlab .(2 weeks +)

Starting with specs..

> OS :Ubunut 14.04 LTS x64
>
> RAM : 8GB
>
> HDD :1TB

I think this meets **basic requirements of gitlab**.

According to the download documentation provided by gitlab.com,

1 . `sudo apt-get install openssh-server ca-certificates postfix`

I installed postfix and configured it for "**Internet site**". I assume that I **do not need to change any setting in postfix** , gitlab will handle other things.

2.

```
wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu-14.04/gitlab-ce_7.10.1~omnibus.2-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i gitlab-ce_7.10.1~omnibus.2-1_amd64.deb
```

works like a charm !

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Browsing to gitlab with

```
Username: root 

Password: 5iveL!fe
```

also works fine!

Now questions arise are .

- Is email necessary for gitlab and for what purposes gitlab uses email other than signup and confirmation?
- If email is only needed for signup purposes or not that necessary, can I as a admin **add users without email confirmation in gitlab**?
- I tried to configure gitlab in following way to **setup smtp settings**.
- Basically many posts suggest edits to following files :

> gitlab.yml
>
> production.rb
>
> gitlab.rb.

Finally I zeroed to the conclusion, that only ***gitlab.rb*** needs to be modified, to configure gitlab.

Other files were required to be configured in previous versions. (Please correct me here if wrong).

for example have a look at this :

[Action mailer SMTP google apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706277/action-mailer-smtp-google-apps)

1)

```
// modifying production.rb

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",

:port                 => 587,

:domain               => "mydomain.com",

:user_name            => "username",

:password             => "password",

:authentication       => 'plain',

:enable_starttls_auto => true  }

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

other way on gitlab.com says :

2)

```
// modify gitlab.rb

external_url 'http://localhost:8888'    //hope this is correct way to configure port 

 gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true

 gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'abcde@gmail.com'

 gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'admin'

 gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'abcde@gmail.com'  // both email from and reply to can be same ?

 gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true

 gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.gmail.com"

 gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587

 gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "abcde@gmail.com"

 gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "abcde"

 gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.gmail.com"

 gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"

 gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true

 gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false

 gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
```

3) yet another way is modifying the yml file.

The mail is not sent. I have tried many , many ways.

Here , when i tried these settings, the **production log** says mail sent.

The sidekiq log specifies ***SMTP error***.

Does seding mail via gmail or any other service over smtp requires us to ***configure digital certificate*** ? I

If yes , does gitlab provide it? Please provide step by step way to do this task.

Other problem is with OAuth. I tried using gmail fo OAuth, but it gives me **500 error** after accepting gmail terms page.(ie when redirect happens to gitlab).

> Client ID
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
>
> Email address
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
>
> Client secret
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Redirect URIs
>
> http://localhost:8888/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
>
> JavaScript origins
>
> https://localhost:8888/

If possible please post video or detailed step by step way to configure email as well as OAuth.

I also request gitlab developers to provide a good gui to configure gitlab or other simple way to do this task. It is very difficult to understand setup process for newbies.

Also, post a very comprehensive step by step guide to configure gitlab. (I have seen documentation but its not very helpful.)

Comment: Finally figured one problem. It was account settings that lead to  Net::SMTPAuthenticationError.


This is very common error if you havent done this setting :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26941927      still need other answers

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message, you helped me a lot !!!